# Confusion regarding the appearance of $\hbar$ in the eigenfunctions of momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, absolute-units

The two images below are from different books. One has the  $\hbar$ in the root below which seems right to me as that gets the dimensions correct but other does not have a $\hbar$. I am confused as to which is correct and why the second book has omitted the $\hbar$  (*Not the one appearing in the exponent but the one outside the integral in the first picture*) ?[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps $p=\hbar k$?

Comment: No I was not talking about the h bar in the exponent but that outside the integral of the first picture.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly it's a standard convention to set ${\bf p}=\hbar {\bf k}$ where $|{\bf k}|$ is the wavenumber and $|{\bf p}|$ is the momentum. Secondly many books, and nearly all working theoretical  physicsts  use "natural units" in which $\hbar=c=1$, so these symbols do not appear in their equations. When they need numbers in physical units (seconds, meters etc) it is easy to restore $\hbar$ and $c$ by looking at the dimensions.

As for delta functions the basic identies are
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dk}{2\pi} e^{ikx}= \delta(x),
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx  e^{-ikx}= 2\pi \delta(k).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct *for momentum*. The second one is *not* given in terms of momentum, but in terms of *angular wave number* $k$. **Note the subscript.** This is a *different* quantity which is related to momentum by

$$p = \hbar k$$

and that accounts for the presence/absence of factors $\hbar$ in the expressions for the wave functions. Namely, since the above gives $k = \frac{p}{\hbar}$, then a simple substitution showns that

$$\phi_k(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ikx}$$

becomes, in terms of $p$,

$$\phi_p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i\left(\frac{p}{\hbar}\right)x}$$

which is just your first expression. You may note this is missing the $\hbar$ under the square root: the reason for this is that *that* factor then appears if we are then trying to normalize this wave function (note here that "normalize" needs to be interpreted loosely, because these are technically *not* normalizable; they belong to the infinitycrust of the rigged Hilbert space, not the "proper" Hilbert space. They're delta vectors.). The normalization is defined by an integral, and when we perform substitution under an integral, we pick up some additional changes due to the differential element, here $dk$, which becomes $\frac{1}{\hbar}\ dp$, so if we want the "normalized" form, we should add that extra factor.

Comment: I was talking about the 'other$\hbar$ factor '. It seems okay when you say that h bar is reintroduced while taking the integral due to the presence of  $d k$ , but then in the first picture the author has written a $\hbar$ even when thee is no integral involved (no $dk$).Could it then just be a matter of choice as @mike stone has pointed out?

Comment: Also they do represent exact same things. The eigenfunctions of the momentum operator. (Th eigenfunctions corresponding to plane wave)

Comment: @Lost : Yeah, the $\hbar$ is included _to make integrals work out_ even if integrals are not being done right there, on the spot. (Technically, I should have added there is no such thing as "normalizing" these wave functions on their own, but you can think of it as kind of a "generalized" normalization. Here it is to make symmetry between the forward and reversed Fourier transform.)

Comment: Your $\phi_p$ should have a $\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}$, not $\sqrt{2\pi}$.  Your text is correct but the expression for your (properly normalized)  $\phi_p$ is not.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: Yes, I did that for illustration of the gist of what is going on. Just rewrote it though to try and make it clearer why it was given as it was.